# Entity Framework - implementing IDbSet

Tags: entity, entity-framework-4.1

I would like to implement IdbSet to provide my DbContext a custom implementation that will essentially serve to filter my data for the currently logged in user (I am working on a multi-tenant application).  The general idea I am going with is very similar to this post: [Can a DbContext enforce a filter policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676280/can-a-dbcontext-enforce-a-filter-policy)

However, it is not clear to me how to make DbContext "know" about how to use my own class that implements IDbSet.  I am having a tough time finding documentation on this.  Any pointers would be helpful!

TIA,
-jle

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure that you cannot create your own implementation of `IDbSet` and pass it to entity framework. Such implementation will lose all stuff related to EF which is internally implemented in `DbSet` itself - by internally I really mean that there is no public API to replace it. `IDbSet` interface is provided not because it is supposed to create your own sets but because it allows mocking sets when unit testing application. The only way you can extend functionality is either:

- Inheriting `DbSet` but I'm afraid that it will not help you as well because methods / properties will not be marked as `virtual`.
- Creating custom `IDbSet` implementation which will wrap `DbSet`. This looks like the best chance but you can still find that `DbContext` doesn't like your new implementation. I gave this very quick try but I was not successful. My implementation worked for persisting but not for querying.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav.  I misunderstood the intent behind/current capabilities of DbContext and IDbSet.  I will be looking for another way to implement multi-tenancy in my application.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can always wrap your data access and add `Where` condition in the wrapper.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka what about Extension methods for DbSet? is this good idea?