# Filtered DBContext : Why not implementing IListSource.GetList()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, devexpress-mvc

Using MVC 5, have implemented Filtered DBSet for our EF as per following solution [IDbSet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745749/2699762)

Everything been working as charm till recently we have an issue where we tried to use this as data source with 3rd party report control.
When running it, it will look for following implementation

```
    IList IListSource.GetList()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
```

I'm not sure why this is tagged as invalid operation and how to overcome it.

Comment: That's because the 3rd party refers to it as `IListSource` hence the explicit interface implementation is being used. Try to replace the method body with `this.FilteredSet.ToList()`

Comment: @haim770 that works