# Force a query on a DBSet before before use

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

This may not be the right approach however, perhaps someone will have a better take on it

I am looking for a way to force a parameter query when calling a DBSet property in a DBContext.

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get { return(User.Where(x=>x.TenantId == TenantId))} set; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a DbContext enforce a filter policy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676280/can-a-dbcontext-enforce-a-filter-policy)

Comment: @CodeNotFound Thank you! I didn't see this one